# Django syncdb not finding sites.site

Tags: django

I'm trying to change my default site from example.com to localhost:8000 and using this json file for my initial data fixture :

```
[
  {
    "model": "sites.site",               
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "domain": "localhost:8000",
      "name": "localhost"
    }
  }
]
```

But syncdb returns DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'sites.site'

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Is the `django.contrib.sites` in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: silly me, I took it out because my admin wasn't working. thanks!

Comment: but that still leaves me with the question as to why the admin module won't work when django.contrib.sites is installed?

Comment: for admin to work, you need `django.contrib.admin`, not `django.contrib.sites`, also you need to enable the admin urlpattern from `urls.py`

Comment: both are activated. and previously sites AND admin worked together, I'm unsure what happened along the way to make one or the other work...

Comment: Its very hard to guess what could have gone wrong. What does not work ? Does it throw an error ?